# How to add Multi-value Filter in cockpit spagobi?

Tags: business-intelligence, spagobi, cockpit

```
select count(*)As CNT,Flat_status,property_name,Building
From xxacl_pn_flat_det_dm
where property_name in ($P{Property})
group by Flat_status,property_name,Building
```

`$P{Property}` returning multiple values in `Dataset` but not in cockpit view

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to pass multi value parameters to the dataset via some analytical driver from the cockpit interface. Well, first you must set the analytical driver to multivalue, then you can use the multivalue parameter syntax from spago, which is : `$P{Property(';,;')}` , this will give you something like:

```
select count(*)As CNT,Flat_status,property_name,Building
From xxacl_pn_flat_det_dm
where property_name in ('example1','example2')
group by Flat_status,property_name,Building
```

Comment: Thanks but {$P{Property(';,;')} not even working in Dataset, Actually $P{Property} which is parameter returning multiple values in Dataset , but its not reflecting in cockpit

Comment: Did you set the Property parameter to string? Also , are you setting your dataset like this :where property_name in ($P{Property(';,;')})  ?

Comment: Property parameter is string
>>where property_name in ($P{Property}) works for multi-value 

where property_name in ($P{Property(';,;')}) won't work